# Camera movement in final scene of 'Into The Wild'

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography, into-the-wild

I just watched 'Into The Wild'. In the final scene the camera rotates around Chris' face, zooms out of the bus and zooms out showing the surrounding area above the bus. [This link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO7a__V-sNI) does not show the close-up rotation but should give an idea of what I am talking about.

How was this done without any cut? Or is it done using some Graphics/Editing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you're after: [Into the Wild Visual Effects](http://www.studiodaily.com/2007/11/into-the-wild-visual-effects/).

It is an interview with Jay Cassidy, who served as Editor for the film. Quoting part of the article:

> *From Close-up to Aerial in One Seamless Shot*
>   The final moving shot
>   starts out on a close-up Hirsch’s face... in the bus
>   then pulls back through the window and rises up over the bus and
>   continues up above until the bus is a mere speck on the screen. This
>   proved to be the most challenging shot of the film for Entity FX. This
>   was made harder because the shot, which actually combines a crane shot
>   and helicopter shot, was done in the wrong order and one different
>   days, one sunny and one rainy.
>
> “A critical thing was that it was shot out of order,” explains Beck.
>   “Ideally you shoot the helicopter first and then the crane move to
>   match it up. But for a number of reasons it was shot the other way
>   around. Pre-vis was really critical. We pre-viz’ed a number of
>   different proposed moves and tried to suggest one that would work both
>   technically and aesthetically. If you look at the last pre-vis and it
>   looks an awful lot like the final. I went up to Alaska and was beating
>   on the Akila guys to make the crane as long as possible to get as high
>   as possible. We had an 82-foot crane that was pulling back from the
>   close-up up as high as it could go. And then we shot the helicopter
>   trying to match the position of the crane on a different day with
>   different weather. So it was our job to match those two together.”
>
> Obviously the crane shot was a lot smoother than the helocopter shot
>   but thre were also differences in position and motion path. In order
>   to smooth out the helicopter shot and to match the cameras, the two
>   shots were transferred at 4K, which allowed them the flexibility to
>   stabilized and push into the shots as needed.
>
> “There was a lot of stabilization of the plates and stabilizing the
>   scale,” explains Marty Taylor, VFX supervisor/lead compositor. “The
>   crane finished below the height of the helicopter and the perspective
>   was different, you saw more of the top of the bus in the helicopter
>   shot than in the crane. This way we were able to lock the two plates
>   together and stabilize and match them. From there figure out what we
>   needed to add as CG elements and matte paintings.”
>
> Because the shots were done on two different days under very different
>   conditions, Entity had to essentially re-create large patches of the
>   landscape.
>
> “One day was rainy and the other day was dry,” recalls Taylor. “On the
>   rainy day all he plants were knocked over and beaten by the rain. On
>   the other shot the plants are dry and standing up. So we had to match
>   that and then we had to make the propeller-wash disappear. The crane
>   is nice and smooth and there’s no wind. Then you get to the helicopter
>   portion and everything is blowing like crazy.”
>
> Once the moves were matched Entity had to create 2D and 3D landscapes,
>   and morph back and forth between those and the real landscape. In
>   addition, Entity FX had to replace a road and production base camp
>   with pristine Alaskan tundra.
>
> “We refer to it as a matte painting but it was actually a 3D
>   reconstruction because it was moving in perspective as the camera was
>   pulling back,” notes Beck.

Comment: ...and all that work can now be done with a consumer drone.